# My ASP.NET app calls a stored procedure in SQL Server but no changes are made?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I'm building an ASP.NET Core web app using MVVM architecture and razor pages.

I have pre-populated values in an editable form modal popup that executes a handler method when save is hit. It's working great, and through breakpoints I can see the information passed is correct. Took a metric ton of trial and error but my handler method builds a `SqlParameter` list and then calls an `ExecuteSqlRaw` method on the string, and converts the parameter list to an array(also correct).

The most annoying part is that through SQL Server Profiler I can see that the stored proc is actually hitting the server, and is returning an OK result, but no changes are made. I can even run the statement listed in the profiler and it actually works just fine, is capable of making changes. I feel like I'm missing something basic.

My handler method:

```
        public IActionResult OnPostChangePart([FromBody] PartNum updatedPart)
        {
            
            var partRecord = _context.tblPartsInventory
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == updatedPart.ID);

            if (partRecord != null )
            {
                string sql = "[dbo].[usp_UpdatetblPartsInventoryBurkeSite] @ID, @txtPart, @txtColor, @Inventory, @txtGroup, @Description, @BinLocation, @Skid";

                var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
                {
                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@ID", Value = partRecord.ID, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int},
                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@txtPart", Value = partRecord.txtPart, IsNullable=true, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar},
                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@txtColor", Value = partRecord.txtColor != null ? partRecord.txtColor : DBNull.Value, IsNullable=true, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar},
                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@Inventory", Value= partRecord.InStock, IsNullable=true, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int},
                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@txtGroup", Value= partRecord.txtGroup != null ? partRecord.txtGroup : DBNull.Value, IsNullable=true, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar},
                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@Description", Value= partRecord.Description != null ? partRecord.Description : DBNull.Value, IsNullable=true, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar},
                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@BinLocation", Value= partRecord.BinLocation != null ? partRecord.BinLocation : DBNull.Value, IsNullable=true, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar},
                    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@Skid", Value= partRecord.Skid != null ? partRecord.Skid : DBNull.Value, IsNullable=true, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar}
                };
                
                _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, parameters.ToArray());
            }
            // Redirect to the main view page
            return Redirect("/InventoryViewer/InventoryViewer");
        }
```

What SQL Server is running in the profiler (direct copy paste runs fine in SSMS):

```
exec sp_executesql N'[dbo].[usp_UpdatetblPartsInventoryBurkeSite] @ID, @txtPart, @txtColor, @Inventory, @txtGroup, @Description, @BinLocation, @Skid',N'@ID int,@txtPart nvarchar(8),@txtColor nvarchar(1),@Inventory int,@txtGroup nvarchar(4000),@Description nvarchar(14),@BinLocation nvarchar(7),@Skid nvarchar(4000)',@ID=144739,@txtPart=N'000-0001',@txtColor=N'0',@Inventory=2247,@txtGroup=NULL,@Description=N'COMMON CASTING',@BinLocation=N'20-B12A',@Skid=NULL
```

I'd originally planned on doing this via LINQ, but the table has 20 year old auditing triggers that are preventing direct edits via my application. Can anyone see what the issue might be? Would I have better luck just trying to work with the triggers? I don't really understand why they're preventing execution but it threw an exception every time.

I've tried creating a unique SQL user and assigning it all the necessary rights to do anything to my table in question(before was just using windows credentials as this will be an internal facing application).

Tried several different approaches to submitting the parameter information, same result.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but my first question would be: are the changes committed? When I worked with such things, I forgot ro out a `$foo->commit();` (for example). It did the changes, but never actually committed them to the db.

Comment: What is the connectionstring used by the application?

Comment: What is the text of usp_UpdatetblPartsInventoryBurkeSite?  Is it possible for it to fail without returning an error to the client?

Comment: In particular with the connection string the mistake a lot of folks make is they have a database where they're checking for changes but their connection string says `User instances / attachDbFileName` which means the application is changing a different, independent copy of the database.

Comment: You are using Entity.  First verify that the server is seeing the query by checking log files in Server using SQL Server Management Studio.  The log file is in the explorer under Management.  With Entity there is a mapping between the c# classes and the database.  Using Migration you may need to update the mapping especially if you are using Core. Old code may be using an EDMX file for the mapping so you would need read the following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx

Comment: Did you try running that command manually in your SSMS and see if it actually runs successfully?

Comment: Also this is just a friendly precaution **just in case** you are new, seem like you are working with an old database. I hope you are working on a copy of it and not directly to the production one?

Comment: What I do in such situations is:
1) put method in try-catch construction
2) add method to log to the file what was the query string.
3) take that query string from the log and try to execute it directly on database management studio.
 This helps to understand whether problem with querry or with the connection string.

Comment: RE "the table has 20 year old auditing triggers that are preventing direct edits via my application.": how exactly can these triggers be preventing your application from making changes? Could the same problems affect your SP?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments everyone, inspired me to carefully go through the whole thing from the beginning and figured out the problem. In my handler method, I was running a linq query to populate partRecord for the if statement. I'd used partRecord in the parameters rather than what was being passed in with the method call, so it WAS actually running correctly, but it was feeding the row it's own information with every save so nothing ever changed.

Thank you for your time all!